# Starting with Twig templates in Symfony2

Tags: templates, symfony

I have this twig template:

```
{% block javascripts %}

    {% javascripts '@AibFrontendBundle/Resources/public/js/update.js' %} 
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js'></script>
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="contents">
    {{ contents|raw }}
</div>

<form action="{{ path('homepage') }}" method="post">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

It shows correctly the content. 
But if I add this line below at the begining

```
{% extends 'AibFrontendBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

It shows layout.html.twig's content but the content I mentioned above is not showed any more..

How to show that content again?

Comment: Could you please show us your layout.html.twig template?

Comment: Inside of layout.html.twig I just have written "aib".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `layout.html.twig` template should include something similar to the following:

```
{% block content %}some optional default content here{% endblock %}
```

which will be replaced by whatever you supply in your page template:

**mypage.html.twig:**

```
{% block content %}
  This will appear in layout.html.twig where I specified the above block
{% endblock %}
```

See the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance) for further details